# Has anyone attempted to add extra senses to a creature through a BCI/Neural interface?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, senses

Basic BCI's (Brain computer interfaces) have been available for quite a while now and allow users to preform rudimentary tasks such as moving prosthetic limbs with force-feedback or moving a mouse on a screen through only neural impulses.

I'm interested if anyone has performed experiments in the direction of adding non-native extra senses to a creature using a neural interface/BCI. For example, feeding a magnetometer's sensor reading or clock data into a BCI and using that to give the person/creature a "sense" of magnetic fields or exact time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**
Yes

**Background**
This subject touches upon a related technologie, namely **[sensory substitution](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/sensory-substitution)**, where a lost sense is replaced by a still functional sense, for instance:

- The [**BrainPort**](https://theplaidzebra.com/device-allows-blind-people-see-tongues/) developed by Wicab that lets blind people taste light (Fig. 1) [(Stronks *et al*., 2016)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/17434440.2016.1237287).
- The, now discontinued, yet still highly popular **[Optacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optacon)** device developed by Telesensory Systems that allows blind folks to scan a normal printed book page with a camera and read it back through braille input via this device [(Stronks *et al* 2016)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0006899315005156?via%3Dihub).

However, you are specifically asking for devices that add novel sensory information, referred to as **[sensory augmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensory_substitution#Sensory_augmentation)**, or **[sensory enhancement](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-94-007-4707-4_106)**. The technique of sensory substitution can,quite obviously, be easily extended to add novel sensory perceptions, simply by using a sensor capable of sensing stimuli that the human sensory systems cannot, for example magnetism, infrared light and what not, for instance:

- Mapping the magnetic North on the human body through auditory or tactile actuators [(Schumann & O'Reagan, 2017)](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep42197).
- Electrically stimulation of the brain in response to otherwise invisible infrared light [(Thomson *et al*., 2013)](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms2497).

<sub>**References**

**-** [Schumann & O'Reagan, *Sci Rep* (2017); **7**: 42197](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep42197)

**-** [Stronks *et al.*, *Brain Res* (2015); **1624**: 140–52](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0006899315005156?via%3Dihub)

**-** [Stronks *et al.*., *Exp Rev Med Dev* (2016); **13**(10): 919–31](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/17434440.2016.1237287)

**-** [Thomson *et al*., *Nature Communications* (2013); **4**: 1482](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms2497)</sub>

[image: BrainPort]
<sup>Fig. 1. BrainPort V100 vision substitution device. source: [Plaid Zebra](https://theplaidzebra.com/device-allows-blind-people-see-tongues/)</sup>